# Scale (apply function?) sparse matrix logarithmically

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am using [scikit-learn preprocessing scaling](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing) for **sparse** matrices.

My goal is to "scale" each feature-column by taking the logarithm-base the column maximum value. My wording may be inexact. I try to explain.

Say feature-column has values: `0, 8, 2`:

- Max value = 8
- Log-8 of feature value 0 should be 0.0 = `math.log(0+1, 8+1)` (the +1 is to cope with zeros; so yes, we are actually taking log-base 9)
- Log-8 of feature value 8 should be 1.0 = `math.log(8+1, 8+1)`
- Log-8 of feature value 2 should be 0.5 = `math.log(2+1, 8+1)`

Yes, I can easily apply any arbitrary function-based transformer with [FunctionTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#custom-transformers), but I want the base of the log change (based on) each column (in particular, the maximum value). That is, I want to do something like the [MaxAbsScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler), only taking logarithms.

I see that `MaxAbsScaler` gets first a vector (`scale`) of the maximum values of each column ([code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L788)) and then multiples the original matrix times `1 / scale` in [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f65d144e3966113d3daec836e443c6d7a5b/sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.py#L62).

However, I don't know what to do if I want to take the logarithms-based on the `scale` vector. Is it even possible to transform the logarithm operation to a multiplication (?) or do I have other possibilities of scipy sparse operations that are efficient?

I hope my intent is clear (and possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logarithm of x in base b is the same as log(x)/log(b), where logs are natural. So, the process you describe amounts to first applying log(x+1) transformation to everything, and then scaling by max absolute value. Conveniently, log(x+1) is a built-in function, `log1p`. Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, maxabs_scale
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
import numpy as np
logtran = FunctionTransformer(np.log1p, accept_sparse=True)
X = csc_matrix([[ 1., 0, 8], [ 2., 0,  0], [ 0,  1., 2]])
Y = maxabs_scale(logtran.transform(X))
```

Output (sparse matrix Y):

```
  (0, 0)        0.630929753571
  (1, 0)        1.0
  (2, 1)        1.0
  (0, 2)        1.0
  (2, 2)        0.5
```

Comment: This is good thinking! Just what I needed, thank you! -- On a similar note, I guess with _sparse_ matrices I cannot first reduce to a minimum range as with `MinMaxScaler`, that is, if feature-column only ranges between 40 and 80, change the minimum to 0 and 40, and then, apply `log1p` as in your answer. -- I would only need to do this for few columns, maybe is it efficient to operate non-sparasely on those columns only then swap?

Comment: It's a strange situation if you have a sparse matrix but some columns have all  values range from 40 to 80. I haven't had to deal with such a situation myself; you may want to post a separate question, as it's different from the above one.